# Can't get rid of this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'each')" when trying to display API response - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have the following code:
**characterActions.js**

```
    export const getCharacters = () => async(dispatch) => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_CHARACTERS_REQUEST })
    
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS,
          payload: data
        })
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_CHARACTERS_FAIL,
          payload: 'error'
        })
      }
    }
```

**characterReducers.js**

```
    import {
      FETCH_CHARACTERS_REQUEST,
      FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS,
      FETCH_CHARACTERS_FAIL,
    } from '../actions/characters/characterConstants'
    
    export const characterListReducer = (state = { characters: {} }, action) => {
      switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_CHARACTERS_REQUEST:
          return { loading: true, characters: [] }
        case FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS:
          return { loading: false, characters: action.payload }
        case FETCH_CHARACTERS_FAIL:
          return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

and **HomeScreen.js** where I want to display the fetched characters

```
    const HomeScreen = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch()
      const charactersList = useSelector(state => state.charactersList)
      const { loading, error, characters } = charactersList
    
      console.log(characters.results)
      
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCharacters())
      }, [dispatch])
    
      return (
        <div>
         {characters.results.map((character) => {
           <h1 key={character.id}>{character.name}</h1>
         })}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

When go into the browser i keep getting
** TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') **

I am trying to fetch data from Rick and Morty API.

Thank you guys!

Comment: API call is asynchronous and you are trying to map before data is returned.  `if(loading) return <Loader />`.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `characters.results` is not an array.

What does it show when you `console.log(characters.results)`?

Comment: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: 'Rick Sanchez', status: 'Alive', species: 'Human', type: '', …}
1: {id: 2, name: 'Morty Smith', status: 'Alive', species: 'Human', type: '', …}
2: {id: 3, name: 'Summer Smith', status: 'Alive', species: 'Human', type: '', …}
3: {id: 4, name: 'Beth Smith', status: 'Alive', species: 'Human', type: '', …}

Answer (score 0):

It may possibly be in error `characters` should be an empty array. For safe, you can either use `||[]`  or simply return a blank array.

```
export const characterListReducer = (state = { characters: {} }, action) => {
      switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_CHARACTERS_REQUEST:
          return { loading: true, characters: [] }
        case FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS:
          return { loading: false, characters: action.payload || [] } // here, in case null data.
        case FETCH_CHARACTERS_FAIL:
          return { loading: false, error: action.payload, characters:[] }  // here, on error
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Add check before looping in case of error

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const charactersList = useSelector((state) => state.charactersList);
  const { loading, error, characters } = charactersList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCharacters());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading please wait...</p>
      ) : error ? (
        <strong>There is error while fetching data, {error}</strong>
      ) : (
        characters.results.map((character) => {
          <h1 key={character.id}>{character.name}</h1>;
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

/// Updated code:

```
const { data } = await axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
dispatch({
  type: FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS,
  payload: data.results // use results instead to make it consistent with above assign
})
```

/// Home screen

```
// remove results now
characters.map((character) => {
  <h1 key={character.id}>{character.name}</h1>;
})
```

Comment: Still not working, same error... :(  The response i get from API is an array of objects, is .map the right function i need for this?

Comment: Ok i found the error.. Let me update solution

Comment: @EduardK: Check now... Updated code:

Comment: Unfortunately i have tried this before... still not working. New error message for this is ×
TypeError: characters.map is not a function :(